# MySQL to generate daily profile views reports with filled gaps

Tags: mysql, date-range

I'm about to plot daily profile views in chart.js. I have two table one for track every day profile visit named "stats_profile_views" and second one carries all date of an year named "calendar"
   [image]
I would like to show last 7 days profile views when logged in each vendor.

Tried following query,

```
SELECT datefield  AS DATE ,`id`, `vendor_id`, `view_date`,IFNULL(view_count,0) AS view_count
FROM (`stats_profile_views` pv)
 RIGHT JOIN bp_calendar ON (DATE(view_date) = bp_calendar.datefield)
WHERE `vendor_id` =  '110'
AND bp_calendar.datefield BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()

GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY `view_date` asc
```

I like to get past 7 days records filled with view_count zero for non-available records in "stats_profile_views" table. But when apply WHERE `vendor_id` =  '110' it fails to return such record and gives only 3 records related with `vendor_id` =  '110'. But it work great without vendor_id filter.

How can I get last 7 days records filled with view_count as zero when filter using vendor_id. Anybody guide me to a solution please.

Comment: I don't understand the GROUP BY clause. There's no aggregation here. And while not necessarily wrong, note that RIGHT JOINS are vanishingly rare.

Comment: right joins are commonly avoided, thus making them increasingly rare.

Comment: I'm getting duplicate dates from both table. used Group By to avoid these duplicate dates

Comment: that use of group by is not a solution, it is a patch at best, what are you needing from the data exactly. do you need to sum() or count(), do you really need `id` in the columns? only sample data and expected result will tell us these things. be very careful of group by in MySQL,you should specify all non-aggregating columns n the group by clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
      c.datefield AS DATE
    , pv.id
    , pv.vendor_id
    , pv.view_date
    , IFNULL(pv.view_count, 0) AS view_count
FROM bp_calendar c
      LEFT JOIN stats_profile_views pv ON (DATE(pv.view_date) = c.datefield)
                  AND pv.vendor_id = '110'
WHERE c.datefield BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
ORDER BY
      pv.view_date ASC
```

When using outer joins the where clause MUST be careful not to override the unmatched rows, otherwise you get the effect of an inner join instead. That's what happened in your original query; because EVERY row is required to have a vendor_id = '110' but an unmatched date cannot have any vendor_id.

Additionally it generally helps to write the query FROM (the table with the all the rows) LEFT JOIN (table with gaps in it). Then include the extra conditions of the left joined table as extra join conditions instead of the where clause.

If you want to group the results then you need to indicate what it is you are attempting to do. Perhaps summing the view_counts? However if you are intending to do that then you would not include columns like `id` in the result.

Also, please, include the table alias in EVERY reference to column.